# A non-square transition matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$S = \{(2, 1, 3, 2, 1), (0, 3, 1, 4, 4), (1, 4, 2, 1, 0)\}$
$T = \{(5, 19, 11, 13, 9), (1, 11, 3, 1, -1), (5, 12, 10, 13, 10)\}$
(*Note that $S$ and $T$ are basis for a particular vector space $V$*)

Find the transition matrix from $T$ to $S$:

After Gauss-Jordan Elimination, I got the following transition matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2\\
2 & 0 & 2\\ 
3 & 3 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, transition matrices are invertible and thus, are square matrices. The above is not a square matrix. Is there something wrong?

Comment: You should've taken each vector in T and represent it as a linear sum of S vectors - and put those components in a column. Then you will get a 3x3 matrix

Comment: @OfekGillon Well, I did just that. But I got a 3x5 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to write each matrix in T as a sum of vectors of S:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 5\\19 \\13 \\11 \\9 \end{pmatrix} =1\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 2\\1 \\3 \\2 \\1 \end{pmatrix} + 2 \cdot
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\3 \\1 \\4 \\4 \end{pmatrix} + 3\cdot
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\4 \\2 \\1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\11 \\3 \\1 \\-1 \end{pmatrix} =-1\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 2\\1 \\3 \\2 \\1 \end{pmatrix} + 0 \cdot
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\3 \\1 \\4 \\4 \end{pmatrix} + 3\cdot
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\4 \\2 \\1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 5\\12 \\10 \\13 \\10 \end{pmatrix} =2\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 2\\1 \\3 \\2 \\1 \end{pmatrix} + 2 \cdot
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\3 \\1 \\4 \\4 \end{pmatrix} + 1\cdot
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\4 \\2 \\1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$$

So the transition matrix will be
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1& -1& 2\\ 2& 0& 2 \\ 3& 3& 1  \end{pmatrix} $$
each column representing the coefficients of summation for each vector in T. (So I don't understand why did you have 2 rows of 0)

Comment: Ok I got it. I was merely computing it without understanding. Thanks.